# Caching Github password

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to cache my GitHub password in Git but when I run the command

```
 "git credential-osxkeychain"
```

I get the error

```
"fatal: cannot exec 'git-credential-osxkeychain': Permission denied".
```

after running:

```
chmod 755 `which git-credential-osxkeychain`
```

I get:

```
usage:  chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-a | +a | =a  [i][# [ n]]] mode|entry file ...
chmod [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-E | -C | -N | -i | -I] file ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permission to the executable credential-osxkeychain:

```
chmod 755 `which git-credential-osxkeychain`
```

Comment: I still get permission denied after running chmod 755 `which git-credential-osxkeychain`

Comment: did you get an error running the chmod command? also - please note, you need the backticks around which git-credential-osxkeychain